# Yii2 сессия очищается после авторизации

Tags: php, yii2, сессия

Здравствуйте.
Делаю простой интернет-магазин. После авторизации пользователя сессия почему-то очищается. Я в `LoginForm.php` немного изменила код, чтобы через `var_dumb()` посмотреть, сохраняется ли в сессию `id` пользователя.

```
public function login()
{
    session_start();
    $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username, $this->password);

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $this->_user->getId();
    var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']);
    if ($this->_user) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Возымело интересный эффект, потому как после вывода мне `id` (он таки сохраняется) я снова перезагружаю страничку и я залогиниваюсь. Но если убрать `var_dumb()`, то сессия стирается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

Настройки конфига фронтенда:

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитесь читать исходники, и таких вопросов возникать не будет. Если пройтись по коду метода `\yii\web\User::login()`, то можно увидеть что он чистит текущую сессию и генерит новый id сессии. И да, для работы с сессиями пользуйтесь `Yii::$app->session`. Он сам умеет открывать сессию когда это нужно, и на него завязаны многие другие компоненты Yii2.

А, по сути вопроса, если вам нужно что-то сохранять между состояниями до и после логина, есть два варианта.

Первый записать значение в сессию после того как пользователь залогинен прямо в `LoginForm`, после выполнения `Yii::$app->user->login()`.

Второй - использовать события `\yii\web\User::EVENT_BEFORE_LOGIN` и `\yii\web\User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN`. То есть, сделать свой Behavior с обработчиками этих событий, и подключить его в конфиг.

Comment: Спасибо. После вашего ответа пошла проверять остальные экшены в контроллере, так как вообще изначально проблема была в том, что после авторизации при добавлении товара в корзину пользователь разлогинивается. Оказывается, в экшене actionAddToCart у меня генерируется новая сессия, как вы и сказали. то же самое в методе login().
Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад быть полезным.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно использовать сессионную обертку Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html , вместо $_SESSION - так будет и правильнее и меньше неожиданностей
2. Напишите `Yii::$app->session->open();` в методе init() контроллера, а не внутри login() - тогда сессия будет открываться и работать до процесса залогинивания.
3. Т.к. контроллеров у Вас много, то сделайте свой "базовый контроллер" `abstract class BaseController extends \yii\web\Controller {` и наследейте все контроллеры от него: `class SiteController extends BaseController`. Собственно в нем и лучше завести метод init() со стартом сессии (`Yii::$app->session->open();`), тогда сессия будет работать во всех контроллерах гарантированно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, это не помогло. 
Сессия работала до залогинивания и до этого, но вот почему-то после всё стирается.